# Mysql unauthenticated users from specific machine

Tags: mysql, centos

So one of our developers VMs is desperately trying to connect to our dev mysql server.

Looking at `show full processlist` shows a number of 'unauthenticated user` lines trying to connect from his specific IP.

Using `ps aux | grep httpd` I can see where a number of threads from httpd are running but I don't know enough to correlate what I'm seeing in the terminal with a reason his machine (not being touched) continually tries to connect.

I've looked in all crontabs and there's nothing that I can see that would do that.

Is there a way to see all processes trying to connect to a specific IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to get the processes connecting to a specific ip

```
#netstat -ant -p | grep "ip:port"
```

This should give you the list, try cleaning up the processes , then do a differential analysis by disabling the crontab once and enabling them but disabling the httpd processes the next time, maybe this will help.